# Creating my own sql wrapper for nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create my own wrapper for mysql for my nodejs application. I have two questions here one of which theres a work around and one where I'm unsure what to do as my javascript skills are still in the learning phase.

First thing: As of right now when you navigate to /api/finance it directs you to the finance controller and the index method. This is currently just for testing purposes trying to figure out how to this kind of stuff.

FinanceController:

```
const sql = require('../../sql.js')

module.exports = {
  index: (req, res, next) => {
    sql.get('test').then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    })
  }
}
```

sql.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { DB } = require('./config')
var connection = mysql.createConnection(DB)

module.exports = {
  get: function(table, columns = '*') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? ', [columns, table], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        resolve(results);
      });
    })
  },
  all: function(table) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM ?? ', table, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        resolve(results);
      });
    })
  },
  where: function(){
    console.log('where called')
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have a `get()` and `all()`. `get()` allows you to pass the table name and an array of columns for example: ['id', 'name'] would get you the id column and name column. `columns = '*'` was an attempt on being able to use one function to either get all columns of the table or specify specific columns however it returns an error: Unknown column in 'field list' so `all()` was my "workaround" however i'd like it to be one function.

Next I can't figure out how to stack/pipe methods? if thats the word.

The goal here would be so I could call the function like this:

```
  index: (req, res, next) => {
    sql.all('test').where().then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    })
  }
}
```

obviously within the `.where()` I would have it like: `.where('id', '=', 'userID')` or something along those lines.
however I'm unsure on how to go about doing that and would like some guidance if its possible. I receive the error: sql.all(...).where is not a function

Comment: `all()` needs to return the query instance: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kmuy2n41/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of immediately launching the SQL, you should simply register the provided information in an instance object (having the same methods) and return that object, and let each method enrich the SQL until the end of the chain is reached and you call a method that will launch the SQL.

The object that is passed from one method to the next (as `this`) maintains state, and collects the different elements of the SQL statement.

Here is one way to do it.

NB: In this demo I used a mock-object for `connection`. This mock object will not actually connect to a database. Its `query` method will just produce the final SQL (with all `?` resolved) instead of a real data set.

```js
// Mock connection object for this snippet only. Just produces the final SQL, not the result
var connection = {
    query(sql, params, callback) {
        let i = 0;
        sql = sql.replace(/\?\??/g, (m) => {
            if (m.length > 1) return [].concat(params[i++]).map(p => "`" + p + "`").join(", ");
            if (typeof params[i] === "string") return "'" + params[i++].replace(/'/g, "''") + "'";
            return params[i++];
        });
        setTimeout(callback(null, sql));
    }
}

// Function to create an instance when a first method call is made on the `sql` object directly
// Chained method calls will keep using that instance
function getInstance(inst) {
    if (inst.columns) return inst; // Keep using same instance in the chain
    inst = Object.create(inst); // No instance yet: create one
    inst.table = null;
    inst.params = [];
    inst.columns = [];
    inst.conditions = [];
    inst.order = [];
    return inst;
}

// This sql object serves a starting point as well
// as proto object for the instance object that
// passes through the chain:
var sql = {
    from(table) {
        let inst = getInstance(this);
        inst.table = table;
        return inst;
    },
    select(...columns) {
        let inst = getInstance(this);
        inst.columns = inst.columns.concat(columns);
        return inst;
    },
    where(column, cmp, value) {
        if (!["<",">","<=",">=","=","!="].includes(cmp)) throw "invalid operator";
        let inst = getInstance(this);
        inst.params.push(column, value);
        inst.conditions.push(cmp);
        return inst;
    },
    orderBy(...columns) {
        let inst = getInstance(this);
        inst.order = inst.order.concat(columns);
        return inst;
    },
    promise() {
        if (!this.table) throw "no table specified";
        // build SQL and parameter list
        let sql = "SELECT *";
        let params = [];
        if (this.columns.length && this.columns != "*") {
            sql = "SELECT ??";
            params.push(this.columns);
        }
        sql += " FROM ??";
        params.push(this.table);
        if (this.conditions.length) {
            sql += " WHERE " + this.conditions.map(cmp => `?? ${cmp} ?`).join(" AND ");
            params.push(...this.params);
        }
        if (this.order.length) {
            sql += " ORDER BY ??";
            params.push(this.order);
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            connection.query(sql, params, function (error, results) {
                if (error) throw error;
                resolve(results);
            });
        });
    }
};

// demo
sql.from("customer")
    .select("id", "name")
    .where("name", ">", "john")
    .where("name", "<", "thomas")
    .orderBy("name", "id")
    .promise()
    .then(console.log);
```

Note that in this implementation it does not matter in which order you chain the `from`, `select`, `where` and `order` method calls. You could even do the following if you wanted to:

```
sql .orderBy("name", "id")
    .where("name", ">", "john")
    .from("customer")
    .where("name", "<", "thomas")
    .select("id", "name")
    .promise()
    .then(console.log);
```